# Найти элемент по части текста с помощью xpath

Tags: xpath

Как найти элемент по части текста с помощью `xpath` ?

Это не работает `//div[contains(text(),'My Text')]`

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    <input id="MyInput">
    "My Text"
</div>
```

Comment: Ну если вообще по вхождению текста (без учета где он расположен в div), то заменить `text()` на `string()`

Comment: @vitidev а если бы надо было достать `input` по части текста под ним, то как действовать ?